# Squash it ... again!

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

If you place the positive integers together and read each set of two adjacent digits at the same time, you get: ([A136414](http://oeis.org/A136414))

```
12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89, 91, 10, 1, 11, ...
```

However, if you squash that sequence again:

```
12, 22, 23, 33, 34, 44, 45, 55, 56, 66, 67, 77, 78, 88, 89, 99, 91, 11, 10, 1, 11, 11
```

and so on.

Your task is to output the sequence of the positive integers ***squashed m times***.

## Squashing process

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
       ↓
    "12345"
       ↓
[12, 23, 34, 45]
```

[Python squashing script](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY49DoIwGIbn9hRfmL6GYoJ_McTegI2x6UBSqjVYSFsGzuLCoqfwIt5GkDi97_A8yfN49WO8dm6ankM02ekz6saAwZYVlGheCal4iJ6SIJJkc-usw3vdY8VbxigpRds4DPMznQcL1oGv3aXBctGJNWDPZZYXOhXSuogVBmkVS3-b5ooxRYlv4uAd6DXg3fuFNChzDlsOOw57DgcOx5lekX_rFw)

## Rules

- You have to receive m (a positive integer) as the input or you can output the sequences for all m
- Numbers in the sequence can appear more than once
- Leading zeros must be removed (eg. `04` is `4`)
- [Default sequence rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info)
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply

## Test cases

```
[In]: 1
[Out]: [12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78, 89, 91, 10, 1, 11, 11, 12, 21, 13, 31, 14, 41, 15, ...]

[In]: 2
[Out]: [12, 22, 23, 33, 34, 44, 45, 55, 56, 66, 67, 77, 78, 88, 89, 99, 91, 11, 10, 1, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 22, 21, 11, 13, 33, 31, 11, 14, 44, 41, 11, 15, ...]

[In]: 3
[Out]: [12, 22, 22, 22, 23, 33, 33, 33, 34, 44, 44, 44, 45, 55, 55, 55, 56, 66, 66, 66, 67, 77, 77, 77, 78, 88, 88, 88, 89, 99, 99, 99, 91, 11, 11, 11, 10, 1, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 22, 22, 22, 21, 11, 11, 11, 13, 33, 33, 33, 31, 11, 11, 11, 14, 44, 44, 44, 41, 11, 11, 11, 15, ...]
```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24933/96037)

Answer (score 13):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 49 bytes

```haskell
f(x:z)=read[x,z!!0]:f z
q=[1..]:map(f.(>>=show))q
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWNw3TNCqsqjRti1ITU6IrdKoUFQ1irdIUqrgKbaMN9fRirXITCzTS9DTs7GyLM_LLNTULoRp1chMz8xRsuRQUgCp84xU0Cooy80oU9BRKErNTFUwMNBVUIExDAwWoHpilAA)

Haskell loves infinite sequences.  Here we get to make an infinite sequence of infinite sequences.

The function `f` takes infinite string of digits and produces numbers formed from the pairs in order.  We combine this with `(>>=show)` to get a function which takes an infinite sequence and produces the next.  We use recursion to create the infinite list of such sequences starting with `[1..]`.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞IFSü«ï
```

Given \$m\$, output the infinite \$m^{th}\$ sequence.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8T7fgw3sOrT68/v9/YwA) or [verify the first 25 results of the first 5 \$m\$](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX/NUVOPyIg4oaSICI//@KInk5GU8O8wqvDr/99MjXCoyz/).

**Explanation:**

```python
∞        # Push the infinite list of positive integers: [1,2,3,...]
 IF      # Loop the input `m` amount of times:
   S     #  Convert the list of integers to a flattened list of digits
    ü    #  For each overlapping pair of digits:
     «   #   Append them together
      ï  #  Convert it back to an integer to remove the leading 0s
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3.8, <s>121</s> 119 bytes

```python
lambda m,n:m<1and n or(n*0==[]or(n:=range(1,n)))and(d:=''.join(map(str,n)))and z(m-1,[int(i+j)for i,j in zip(d,d[1:])])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzLDsIgEEX3fsXsOqNoxMbEEPmSygKDD4gMBLuRn8fWpAt39@SenPwZn4n7Uy6t6kt72Xh1FqJgFc/SsgOGVJDXe60HMy@li@XHDaVgIpoMdEp33S4kzxhtxvdYlgsqxq0Ug@cR/SbQPRXwIoBnqD6jE26QypChlsvs1Kkqj0SrBQ//2P@wfQE)

`m` is the number of squashes applied and `n` controls the length of the output.

---

Same idea, except split over two functions (and somehow the exact same number of characters):

```python
lambda m,n:y(m,range(1,n))
y=lambda m,a:m<1and a or(d:=''.join(map(str,a)))and y(m-1,[int(i+j)for i,j in zip(d,d[1:])])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3LCsIwEEX3fkV2ncFRiEWQ0H5J7WIkPlLMJMRump@PqaDg8nAu98RlfgRpTzGV3J/Lk/3FsvIkZgFPieV@BU2CuFn6n2TjO81iFauQwJq@afZTcAKeI7zmRIyIq68fO02DkxncdsJbSMrRpJyo7CJYsoM2I45YYlo3uab0sba@ePjH9oPlDQ)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 5):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 21 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous infix lambda, taking `m` as left argument and the number of elements of the sequence to generate as right argument.

```
{⍵↑{⍎¨2,/∊⍕¨⍵}⍣⍺⍳1+⍵}
```

`{`…`}` "dfn"; `⍺` is `m` and `⍵` is the number of elements to generate.

`1+⍵` increment the number of elements (to handle the case of 1)

`⍳` generate the **i**ntegers 1…`m`+1

`{`…`}⍣⍺` repeat application of the following function, `m` times:

`⍕¨⍵` format each number in the sequence

`∊` enlist (flatten)

`2,/` concatenate adjacent characters

`⍎¨` evaluate each

`⍵↑` take as many elements as requested

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q37Uu/VR28TqR719h1YY6eg/6uh61Dv10AqgcO2j3sWPenc96t1sqA3iAgA&f=M1RIUzAy4DICUsYWXMZAytwEAA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 64 bytes

```javascript
f=(m,n)=>n?[...f(m,n-1),m--?+f(m,n+2).join``.substr(n-1,2):n]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcrLDkAwEIXhvSfpRDuhdhI8iEhcK4QZafH6ddlJLP/vnLk5G9fZadsVcT94bzKxSoIsp6JERPOUikGuShXhW6EGnHmiukZ3tG634j5IDSlVaVn5jsnxMuDCozDiHiKA4Iv6D5MX/QU)

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
!¡ȯmdẊeṁdN→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9odXNr//8hwqHIr21k4bqKZeG5gWRO4oaS////Mg)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ị+D€FVƝƊ⁹¡¥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//4buLK0TigqxGVsadxorigbnCocKl/8Onw75H//80MP80)

1-indexed, takes \$m\$ on the right and \$n\$ on the left to give the \$n\$th term of the sequence.

It seems like there should be a non-naive method as well, but the patterns that manifest in the single digits may not be as real as they seem.

```
        ⁹¡     Repeat m times
 +        ¥    starting with n + m:
  D€           digits of each
   €           (implicitly rangifies on first iteration),
    F          flatten,
     VƝ        concatenate each pair of adjacent digits into an integer.
ị              Get the n'th element of the result.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 20 bytes

```
J+.ro{im2CO}3MVE!j.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V9dkPrfS1uvKL86M9fI2b/W2DfMVTFLT/t/bXjOf2MFQwMDAy4jBUtLLmMFSwA)

```
J    # Duplicate M
+.ro # Range [1..M+1]
{
 im  # Implode (concatenate digits)
 2CO # Chunks with overlap length 2 ("ABC"2CO -> "AB" "BC")
}
3MV  # Move the 3rd item (N) to top of stack
E!   # Evaluate that many times
j.+  # Keep the top M numbers
```

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 13 bytes (invalid violates [default sequence rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info))

```
ro{im2CO}x/E!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V9dkPq/KL86M9fI2b@2Qt9V8X9teM5/QwVTLiMFS0suYwVLAA)

```
ro    # Range 1..N
{
 im   # Implode (concatenate digits)
 2CO  # Chunks with overlap length 2 ("ABC"2CO -> "AB" "BC")
}
x/    # Reorder stack putting `m` on top
E!    # Eval `m` times
```

Comment: So `N` is the size of the original list? I don't see how that could be allowed by the rules

Comment: I believe this answer is invalid. Note that a different number of elements are returned for the same `N` and different `m`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V9dkPq/KL86M9fI2b@2Qt9V8X9teM5/QwVjLiMgNlYwBgA "Burlesque – Try It Online").  Also, the input `2 1` gives an error: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V9dkPq/KL86M9fI2b@2Qt9V8X9teM5/IwVDAA "Burlesque – Try It Online")

Comment: It is more the fact that the infinite list cannot easily be operated on (in this way) in a way which will return an answer in finite time. It generates the list for `[1..N]` input elements "squashed" `M` times. As `N` approaches infinity, it produces the full sequence.

Comment: I understand that but I don't think it's allowed by the rules. `n` should either be the number of elements returned or the index of an element in the `m`th list, not the upper bound of the starting list. See [Default Sequence Rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 96 bytes (@math junkie)

```
def f(n,c=0):
 while n<1:c+=1;yield c
 for s in f(n-1):
  for b in`s`:
    if c:yield int(c+b)
    c=b
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5NDoIwEEbX9BSzbIMkgButchfC0IZJSkvaMYazuGFjPJO3EUS3L-_7ebymmYfg62V53tgWp3fbGwtW-gM2pdIC7gM5A_5aacyb6jKTcT2gABsiJCC_uUW1mV_UrahNrRYZWUC96-RZYt4pkWHT_XbONoYRiE3kENzaNE4hMlByhEZMcc2Ao8RyJ9LKozrUZanUXvA__AE)

TIL: Apparently one can mix spaces and tabs in Python 2.

#### Old [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 101 bytes

```
def f(n,c=0):
 while n<1:c=c+1;yield c
 for s in f(n-1):
  for b in`s`:
   if c:yield int(c+b)
   c=b
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5NDoIwEIX3nGKWbcAEcKModyEMnTBJaUk7xnAWN2yMZ_I2UtHl-_L-Hq95kdG7el2fN6HD6W0GQ0DKFdiWusngPrI14K5Vgy3m1WVhYwfADMgHiMAumQ9Vsn5Rv6EudkkCE2CzB9iJwrzXCWPb_8bOFPwELCaI93Zrm2YfBDhaRpPNYUuB5ShqJ4rUURd1WWq9F_xffwA)

Comment: You can save some bytes by mixing tabs and spaces: [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5BDoIwEEXXcIpZtgESwI2i3IV0aMMkpSXtGMNZ3LAxnsnbWIIu5-X9_-f5XlaevGu37XVnU50_atQGjHAl9rXscnhMZDW4W9Nhj0VzXUnbETAH4wNEILfLVZPUbCcqkSEO6crIAHaHTo4FFkomir36LV1M8DMQ68De21Q1Lz4wULSEOl9CCoGlyOIgwoiTLNu6lvIo-L_8BQ)

Comment: Wow, is that a Python 2 thing? I'm pretty sure it is illegal in Python 3.@mathjunkie

Comment: @loopywalt Yes, [see this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58/92689).

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
Tɾ$(ṅ2lĖ)Ẏ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJUyb4kKOG5hTJsxJYp4bqOIiwiIiwiNTBcbjIiXQ==)

Takes `number of items to generate` then `how many times to squash`

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
‘RDFṡ2ḌƲ⁴¡³ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//4oCYUkRG4bmhMuG4jMay4oG0wqHCs@G7i////zEy/zI)

Comment: Seems to be incorrect for 9, 1?

Comment: @UnrelatedString Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## Rust + Itertools, 249 bytes

```rs
use itertools::*;let f=|s:Box<dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item=u32>>|Box::new(s.flat_map(|a|(0..=a.log10()).rev().map(move|t|a/10u32.pow(t)%10)).tuple_windows().map(|k:(u32,u32)|k.0*10+k.1));let g=|n|{let mut k=f(Box::new(1..));for _ in 0..n{k=f(k)};k};
```

Playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=11fa065d958a13e4a9d68dc2de7b9b12

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, <s>143</s> 139 bytes

```java
n->m->{int r[]=new int[n],i,j=0;for(;j++<m;){var s="";for(i=0;i<n;r[i]=new Byte(s.substring(i,i+++2)))s+=j<2?i-~i+""+-~i*2:r[i];}return r;}
```

Takes inputs \$n,m\$ and outputs the first \$n\$ values of the \$m^{th}\$ sequence.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jVCxboMwEN3zFSdPpgdWi5QlxlTtUKlDp4yUwUkgMsUG2SYViuivU0Mide1in9/zvbv3GnmRSXP6mo@tdA4@pDLXDYDz0qsjNIFlg1ctqwdz9Koz7O1eZO/GV@fKxv/7pIwvyjyHGsRsklwn@TVAYItSmOp7pU0Zq7gRj7zuLOUNYqZ5dL1IC04QsqIqsCoz3Bbq1vc6@oo65oaD81aZM1WxQsQ0iiKHosnSZ5X8KCQEw/WQ7pZGPtnKD9aA5dPMN8FtPxza4PZu@tKpE@gQBN2vmkUpoyUTWLYEI9ItX1/rQgHR4omDzsQ2nIjRygHsR@crzbrBsz6o@NZQogVBjYQHEYIGyQ4@PcG//F6slaNjvrsNpjWTfd@O1ET3Qgdfy/BpM82/)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->m->{                  // Method with two integer parameters & integer-array result
  int r[]=new int[n],    //  Create the result-list of `n` amount of 0s
      i,                 //  Index-integer `i`, uninitialized for now
  j=0,i;for(;j++<m;){    //  Loop `j` in the range [1,m):
    var s="";            //   String `s`, starting empty
    for(i=0;i<n          //   Inner loop `i` in the range [0,n):
        ;                //     After every iteration:
         r[i]=           //      Replace the i'th value in the result-array to:
           new Byte(     //       Convert the following String to an integer,
                         //       (to put it in the integer-array & to remove leading 0s)
            s.substring( //        A substring of String `s`,
              i,i+++2))) //        in the character index-range [i,i+2)
                         //        (and increase `i` by 1 afterwards with `i++`)
      s+=                //    Append to String `s`:
         j<2?            //     If `j` is 1, thus the first iteration of loop `j`:
             i-~i        //      Append (2*i+1) to the String
             +""+-~i*2   //      as well as (2*i+2)
                         //      (so the .substring-indices won't be out-of-bounds)
           :             //     Else:
            r[i];        //      Append the i'th integer of the result-array instead
  }return r;}            //  After the loops: return the result-array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 16 bytes

```
LsM.:jkb2<yFShQE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/36fYV88qKzvJyKbSLTgj0PX/f0MDAy5jAA)

Takes `n` (number of elements to generate) then `m` on separate lines.

```
LsM.:jkb2<yFShQE
L                 Create a lambda with variable b:
     jkb           - Concatenate elements of b
                     (e.g. [1,2,3,4] -> "1234")
   .:   2          - Produce all 2-element sub-strings
                     (e.g. "1234" -> ["12","23","34"])
 sM                - Convert to integers
                     (e.g. ["12","23","34"] -> [12,23,34])
            ShQ   Range from 1 to n+1
          yF   E  Apply the above lambda m times
         <        Keep the first n elements
```

Answer (score 1):

## [lin](https://github.com/molarmanful/lin), 41 bytes

```
$`1`d \; `it
\ns `' `flat2`xp \; `'
`_` N
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-lin) Generates an infinite list of infinite lists.

Pretty-printed output version (run with `-i` flag if using local interpreter):

```
; ( 40`t ) `' 10`t `__ wrap_
$`1`d \; `it
\ns `' `flat2`xp \; `'
`_` N
```

lin is a stack-based language I began working on a few years back, but have recently been dusting off with new features and inspirations.

### Explanation

- `` $` 1`d `` push infinite list `[1..]`
- `` \; `it `` iterate infinitely...

  - `` \ns `' `flat `` convert each number to digit list and flatten
  - `` 2`xp \; `' `` pairwise map...

    - `` `_` N `` convert pair to number

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 102 bytes

```py
def z(m,n):a=range(1,n);exec'd="".join(map(str,a));a=[int(i+j)for i,j in zip(d,d[1:])];'*m;return a[m]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VczBCgIhFEDRfV8hs5n3SgIn2oz4JeJC0ikF34gZlD9vU9Ci5Vncm1/1ttLUu/MLa5A44WxVsXT1IDZI//SX0alhOMY1ECSb4V4Lt4jSKh2oQjhEXNbCAo8sEGshg@NOi9mgkeM@yeLroxCzOpmeyydp21ucEXc/Tv88fdnf)

It's not the shortest Python 2 script here, but the approach is very different  to @loopy walt's so I thought it was worth sharing anyways.

The first version of the code, when given an input *n*, returned a sequence containing at least the first *n* elements, but @math junkie pointed out that this is not allowed in the sequence rules.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Code Golf and interesting answer. Unfortunately, I believe this answer is invalid. According to the [Default Sequence Rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info), if your function takes a parameter `n`, it should return either the `n`th element of the sequence, or the first `n` elements, and this answer does neither

Comment: For example, note that `n=4` using your answer returns a different number of elements for each `m`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcyxDsIgEIDh3acgXXqnxKTVqYQnaToQoQoJBzkxUV4e28HB8Uv@/PlTHonG1qxbRYUoCSej2dDdwbBBube79VZ33TkkTxBNhmdhaRCV0bOnAv4UcE0svAzCk6g@g5V2HqYFF9Ufo2JXXkzCtMx7X7fxFfHw0/iny672BQ "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: I interpreted the rule "Given some index _n_ it can return all entries up to the _n_-th one in the sequence" as meaning it has to return _at least_ the first _n_ entries, but your interpretation is clearly more in line with the intent.